# Può considerarsi "manifattura" la fabbricazione di oggetti totalmente robotizzata?

Tags: word-usage, etymology, word-meaning, latin

L'etimologia di `manifattura` è "fatto a mano", da `manufactus` (latino). Oggi però il termine ha perso il senso originario e si riferisce a qualsiasi mezzo produttivo: mani o macchine.

Mi suona strano però associare questa parola a quelle tipologie di industrie che si servono quasi esclusivamente di robot piuttosto che a quelle che si servono di un equo mix di uomini e macchine. Per esempio, nell'industria dei semiconduttori e delle nanotecnologie, Intel ha reso pubblici alcuni video dove viene mostrato il livello di automazione quasi totale delle proprie fabbriche: dal trasporto dei materiali ai vai reparti della fabbrica, all'inserimento automatico di tali materiali all'interno delle macchine, alla fabbricazione autonoma, al collaudo robotizzato, al confezionamento meccanico e infine al magazzino.

Insomma, questa è `manifattura`?

Comment: Ma certo. Il termine è talmente vasto che per metonimia arriva a significare addirittura fabbrica o industria, oltre al sistema di produzione in sé.

Comment: Benvenuto su Italian.SE, @davide!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Certo: molte parole rimangono in uso anche quando i dettagli del loro etimo sono venuti meno. Si parla ancora – per rimanere a esempi simili al tuo – di **manoscritto** (di un libro o un articolo) anche se quasi sempre l'autore lo ha scritto al computer (e in precedenza con la macchina per scrivere), così come oggetti di vario tipo, più o meno astratti, si possono **maneggiare**, **manipolare** e **manovrare** senza usare le mani.

Si parla poi di **navigazione** anche riferendosi agli aerei o ad altri veicoli, di **film** anche se la pellicola non si usa quasi più, e lo stesso **libro** si riferisce a un supporto (uno strato della corteccia) che non si usa più da millenni per scrivere.

Penso che gli esempi siano innumerevoli, e sono affascinanti perché nelle parole moderne sopravvivono, a mo' di fossili, tracce di usi e tecniche precedenti.